# What is causing an "Error connecting to native app" when connecting to a native host application with connectNative() in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am implementing communication between a web page and a Mac application using Chrome's Native Messaging feature. All seems to go well until I make the javascript call to chrome.runtime.connectNative("my_native_host_app_name"), which produces the following error in the console:

```
Error in event handler for runtime.onMessageExternal: Error connecting to native app: com.allinlearning.nmhforbrowserextension
Stack trace: Error: Error connecting to native app: com.allinlearning.nmhforbrowserextension
    at Object.<anonymous> (extensions::runtime:189:11)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Object.handleRequest (extensions::binding:55:27)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (extensions::binding:318:32)
    at chrome-extension://gldheanjpgopipommeingjlnoiamdfol/background.js:19:27
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at EventImpl.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:395:22)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Event.$Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function) [as dispatchToListener] (extensions::utils:65:26) extensions::event_bindings:383
EventImpl.dispatch_extensions::event_bindings:383
EventImpl.dispatchextensions::event_bindings:401
$Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function)extensions::utils:65
messageListenerextensions::messaging:190
EventImpl.dispatchToListenerextensions::event_bindings:395
$Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function)extensions::utils:65
EventImpl.dispatch_extensions::event_bindings:378
EventImpl.dispatchextensions::event_bindings:401
$Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function)extensions::utils:65
dispatchOnMessageextensions::messaging:304
```

The actual call that seems to cause this error (line 19 in the ref to background.js in the stack trace) is:

```
port = chrome.runtime.connectNative("com.nmhforbrowserextension");
```

To give more context, it is invoked from a listener:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(

  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    //var imgdata = JSON.stringify(request.imgdata);
    //process it somehow here

    port = chrome.runtime.connectNative("com.allinlearning.nmhforbrowserextension");

    if (port)
       console.log("connectNative() returned a non-null port");
    else
       console.log("connectNative() returned null for the port");
});
```

It never gets to the if statement. The doc I am primarily using is Chrome [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host).  At the bottom of the doc it has a section to provide help with common errors [Debugging native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-debugging). I can't seem to relate the "Error connecting to native app" to any of the specifically mentioned errors.

The complete contents of my extension manifest file ("manifest.json") are:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "AIL Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "New Reader",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
     },

    "externally_connectable": {
    // Extension and app IDs. If this field is not specified, no
    // extensions or apps can connect.
    "ids": [
      "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
    ],
    // Match patterns for web pages. Does not affect content scripts.
    // If this field is not specified, no webpages can connect.
    "matches": [
      "http://localhost/charles/qrexttest/*"
    ],

     "permissions": [
                   "nativeMessaging",
                    "tabs",
                    "activeTab",
                    "background",
                    "http://*/", "https://*/"
                    ],

    // Indicates that the extension would like to make use of the TLS
    // channel ID of the web page connecting to it. The web page must
    // also opt to send the TLS channel ID to the extension via setting
    // includeTlsChannelId to true in runtime.connect's connectInfo
    // or runtime.sendMessage's options.
    "accepts_tls_channel_id": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the possible causes for the "Error connecting to native app: [native messaging host id]" is the absence of the required `nativeMessaging` permission.

[Declare](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) the `"nativeMessaging"` permission in the manifest file, reload the extension and try again.

<sub>(the fact that [`chrome.runtime.connectNative`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connectNative) and [`sendNativeMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendNativeMessage) are available without this permission [is a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=445727).)</sub>

Comment: That permission is in indeed in the extension manifest. But I got suspicious about whether my native host manifest was even being processed, so I completely removed it from the NativeMessagingHosts folder (in Google/Chrome/Default) and got the exact same error. Seems this proves the error is prior to the manifest being parsed.  Could "Error connecting to native app" be caused by an inability to find the manifest at all?

Comment: @Alyoshak Are you *really* sure that the nativeMessaging (spelled like that) is in your manifest, and that you (re)loaded your extension after adding this permission to the manifest file? Edit your question and show the manifest file. And from where did you call connectNative?

Comment: Yes.  An enlightening discussion from Dec 2013 is here https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/0tpZnA0qezY. That's where I learned that nativeMessaging had to be in the manifest.

Comment: @Alyoshak The `"permissions"` key in your manifest file is misplaced. It is currently a subkey of `externally_connectable`. Move the last `}` at the end of the manifest file to after `"http://localhost/charles/qrexttest/*"]`, reload your extension and try again.

Comment: That fixed it.  I have a new error "Specified native messaging host not found", but I see there's an entire section on this error in the Debugging section of the doc. I'll mark this as correct.  I humbly admit there was nothing "incomplete" with regard to the docs on this one.  I didn't have the json spec correct.