# how to check accessed directories by chrome through extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i am developing a chrome extension for monitoring the files accessed  or directories accessed by chrome **i.e**

### while uploading file to google Drive you browse directories which file to upload

. In other words a directory monitoring extension. Further
    feature can be added.

**

1. This is security issue which i am trying to solve.i searched but
   Google did not help me that much.

### **

Comment: Extensions can't do that. You can write an external utility that runs in the OS and monitors the files. Your extension can communicate with that utility via nativeMessaging API.

Comment: For more information on `nativeMessaging` refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169384/what-is-native-messaging-between-applications-and-how-does-it-work